# .NET Paste some content from one XML to another XML File

Tags: .net, xml, copy, paste

I am trying to copy a certain "range" of elements from one .xml file and "paste" them into another. I am using REGEX to copy the "range" from the one .xml. This part is working.

```
Public Function ParseCalibrationFile(ByVal ocalcFile As String) Implements IXmlServices.ParseCalibrationFile

    Dim poleImages As String = Nothing

    Try

        Dim imageData As String = File.ReadAllText(ocalcFile.ToString)

        poleImages = Regex.Match(imageData, "((?s)        <PoleImages>(.*?)        <\/PoleImages>)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Value.ToString


    Catch ex As Exception

        Omitted on purpose

    End Try

    Return poleImages

End Function
```

This returns poleImages as a string listed below, which is exactly what I need. This part works great.

[image]

When I go to paste it to the other .xml the formatting is "blown out". I get the following, note that the PoleImages should be on the next line, below PPLChildElements:

[image]

I am currently using XmlTextWriter to create my .xml. and using WriteString to "paste" the copied information. I have tried a few other things with no luck. WiteCData gets me the closest, keeping the formatting but obviously I cant use that.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to better "paste" this in?

Comment: What are you pasting into? What editor?  It looks like the XML is being escaped as if it's content, and not being treated as XML.  You might just consider doing this in your code, to avoid changes that some editors make on content.  Good luck.

Comment: There is only one way to parse XML, and that way is an XML parser. Any solution using regex for XML (either to extract information, or to modify the XML source) is wrong. Use an XML API (for example .NET's `System.Xml.XmlDocument`) to load and modify the input document.

Comment: @Tomalak Thank you, could you point me to some examples/tutorials on how to do that? I am new to writing to XML. The XML i am trying to paste into is being created using the XML API. 99% I am creating from code. The last part is adding this "copied" section to the end of what is created via code. I unfortunately cant "hard" code it because it it different each time.

Comment: You have to show more of your code. As long as you are still working with the XML, you should not convert it to string with an `XmlTextWriter`, like you're currently doing. You should keep it as an `XmlDocument` or whatever it is you're using. And there are countless examples of how to work work with XML in .NET, you don't need me to point you to one.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work using my parsed string by using WriteRaw. I still parse from the XML file using REGEX and then take that string and:

```
Dim poleImageData As String = ParseCalibrationFile(calibrationFileLocation)

        xmlWriter.WriteRaw(Environment.NewLine)
        xmlWriter.WriteRaw(poleImageData)
        xmlWriter.WriteRaw(Environment.NewLine)
```

I had to add some NewLine's before and after and WriteRaw works.